# How to draw horizontal lines around an icon?

Tags: css

I am trying to draw two solid horizontal lines on ech side of an icon with the following codes. But as I display the `li` tags as `inline-block`,the lines vanish.

```css
.icon-wrapper {
  display: table;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}
.center-icon ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center-icon ul li hr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #8c8c8c;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-icon">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <hr>
    </li>
    <li><span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <hr>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use borders?  border-top and border-bottom?

Comment: You need to set a width on the `<hr>` with a unit (e.g. 100px) instead of a percentage since no ancestor has a defined width. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u4g1e35b/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with pseudo-elements.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

.iconwrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.iconwrapper::before,
.iconwrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.fa {
 border:1px solid black;

  padding: .25em;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="iconwrapper"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to remove the `<hr />` and give the `borders`:

```css
.icon-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -14px auto 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.center-icon ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
  width: 75px;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
Vertical
<div class="center-icon">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

Horizontal
<div class="center-icon">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="icon-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]